# Drop all things in a Mongo collection with Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am new to meteor.js and MongoDB.
I can't figure it out how to delete all objects that I previously inserted into the Mongo collection Object. The method in meteor doc is not working for me.`Tasks.remove({});` not working.

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.myInsertButton.events({
    'click a': function () { 
        Tasks.insert({
            text: num,
            createdAt: new Date() // current time
        });

    }
  }); 
  Template.myResetButton.events({
    'click a': function () {
        Tasks.remove({});   // NOT WORKING HERE
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What happens if you execute `Tasks.remove({});` from the web browser's Javascript console after loading the app?  Could removal be prohibited by subscription policy and Meteor.allow/deny?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, [you can't update or remove more than one object at a time from the client](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3271).

The solution is to define a [Meteor method](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-methods) on the server that removes the tasks, then call it from the client.

Alternatively, you can remove tasks one by one from the client, but this is less efficient.